# how can to disabled input from on html javascript with array dynamic

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, spring, spring-boot

```html
<tr th:each="StockinReport,iStat:${listStockinReport.getStockinDetail()}" name="line_items">
  <td>
    <input type="text" class="form-control quantity_in" name="quantity_in" id="quantity_in">
  </td>
  <td>
    <input type="text" class="form-control unit_price" name="unit_price" id="unit_price">
  </td>
</tr>
```

```js
let input1 = document.getElementById("quantity_in");
let input2 = document.getElementById("unit_price");

input1.disabled = true;
input2.disabled = true;
```

This is my image picture error on thymleaf spring
[image]

Hello all brother can you help me to hidden array input that I get this data from the spring controller and show it on thymleaf but I want to disable all input and now I can disable only the first row and another row don't disabled

Comment: [`document.getElementById`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById) returns the first match with that `id`. See to it that your `id` are unique as they should be and select the inputs using their class [`document.querySelectorAll('.quantity_in, .unit_price')`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll).

Comment: let input1 = document.querySelectorAll('.quantity_in,.unit_price');

when i follow i can get all data but when i use input1.disabled=true; is don't work

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate through the elements of your parent element (in this case the tr) and mark them as readonly dynamically.

```js
<script>
    const child = document.getElementsByName("line-items")[0].children
    for (let i = 0; i < child.length; i++) {
        let currentElement = child[i]
        for (let j = 0; j < currentElement.children.length; j++) {
            currentElement.children[j].disabled = currentElement.children[j].tagName == "INPUT"
        }
    }
</script>
```